# Error with `fopen` and QT(MinGW)

Tags: c++, file-io, mingw

I have the following code in my QT application:

`FILE * file = fopen(m_fileName.c_str(), "rb");`

, where the type of `m_fileName` is `std::string`.
This code works fine in Visual Studio2012. But in QT 4.7.4 (MinGW compiler) my program crashes at this line.

I don't really know what is wrong with this code. I haven't used MinGW a lot, so there must be something I don't know about.

**Update:**

Code from `main.cpp`:

```
std::string fileName = "test1.bmp";
m_pTexture1 = new Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fileName);
if (!m_pTexture1->Load()) {
   return;
}
```

Simplified code of `Texture.cpp`:

```
Texture::Texture(GLenum TextureTarget, std::string FileName)
{
    m_textureTarget = TextureTarget;
    m_fileName = FileName;
}

bool Texture::Load()
{
    try {
        FILE * file = fopen(m_fileName.c_str(),"rb");
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout « "Error loading texture '" « m_fileName;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code of `Texture.h`:

```
class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(GLenum TextureTarget, std::string FileName);
    bool Load();

private:
    std::string m_fileName;
    GLenum m_textureTarget;
    GLuint m_textureObj;
    unsigned int width, height;
    unsigned char * data;
};
```

Yes, @PaulMcKenzie was right. I tried to print `m_fileName` in constructor and it crushed the program. Looks like `m_fileName` can't be initialized. But, I don't know why this happens.

**Update 2**

I figured out it crushes because of `printf` and other C i/o functions. Very strange.

Comment: Instead of a single line out of your program, please look at this example:  http://ideone.com/d3VyBz  Are you saying that the simple code there crashes?  As to the single line, we don't know if `m_fileName` has been corrupted, or is a member variable of a class and the instance of this class is invalid, etc.

Comment: This isn't Qt related. Please don't tag it qt. (Use QFile, QIODevice etc to read a file using the Qt APIs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is syntax error. (bracket)

`FILE * file = fopen(m_fileName.c_str()), "rb");
                                       ^
                                    this one`

Did you compile successful?

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry. This mistake is here, on the site, I edited it.

Comment: Can you debug (step by step) your source to know where it crashed? Is it run inside constructor function? or it crashed in somewhere?